# Configuring GitHub to automatically build new ruby gems

Tags: build, rubygems, github

I just added a new gem to GitHub. Check it out:

http://github.com/esilverberg/google_otg

Unfortunately, it cannot be installed via the command:

`gem install esilverberg-google_otg`

And this is because it is not showing up in:

http://gems.github.com/list.html

So it is not being built by GitHub. I followed their really simple instructions:

- I checked the "RubyGem" checkbox in my project
- I have a .gemspec, created by Jeweler.
- I ran this [script](http://gist.github.com/16215) to simulate their environment and it was OK
- I have waited > 15 min

Can someone tell me why this is not being built by GitHub? Anecdotally, about 50% of the gems I use I have been unable to actually install from GitHub - I end up having to install from rubyforge.org. This leads me to believe there is something a lot of people are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Revving the version seemed to cause GitHub to finally build my gem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a link when you reload your project's github page on the right [the gem] to "rebuild gem" if you don't want to do the version bump.  Then it takes a few minutes to show up